# Node-Postgres UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: A query must have either text or a name. Supplying neither is unsupported

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, async-await, node-postgres

I am currently getting the following UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error when trying to use node-postgres Pool but I'm having difficulites understanding where it's coming from and what I need to look at to fix it:

> "(node:14208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: A query must
> have either text or a name. Supplying neither is unsupported.
> ...
> (node:14208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch()."
> ...

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require("./database");
const adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
const homeRouter = require('./routes/home');
const aboutRouter = require('./routes/about');
const collectionRouter = require('./routes/collection');
const contactRouter = require('./routes/contact');

app.use(express.static('public')); 

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server Running..."); 
})

app.use(db.query); 

app.use(adminRouter);
app.use(homeRouter);
app.use(aboutRouter);
app.use(collectionRouter);
app.use(contactRouter);
```

**database.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;
const router = express.Router();

//insures that the .env file is only run in a development environment and not a production environment
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){
    //requires the the .env file configuration be run first hiding all info hidden via the .env file
    require('dotenv').config();
}

const pool = new Pool({
    user: "postgres",
    password: process.env.DB_PW,
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    database: "store",
    max: 20,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 0
});

module.exports = {
    query: (text, params) => {
        return pool.query(text, params)
    }
}
```

**routes**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../database");

//Comics
router.get('/collection/comics', async(req, res) => {

    try{
        const { id } = req.params;
        const item = await db.query("SELECT * FROM collection", [id]);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

    res.render('comics', {title: 'Comics', condition: false});
})

...

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `app.use(db.query);` - uh, don't do that?

Comment: @Bergi Thank you that helped a lot. I must have must have misunderstood something in the referernces I was using.